# Unable to parse date in the code and flow is not going to while loop

Tags: perl, db2, dbi

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:DB2:xxx",'xxx','xxx',{ RaiseError => 0,  AutoCommit => 1 })
or die ("Could not connect to database :".DBI->errstr);

my %hash =
(
'2017-01-01 00:00:00' => '2017-01-31 00:00:00',
'2017-02-01 00:00:00' => '2017-02-28 00:00:00',
'2017-03-01 00:00:00' => '2017-03-31 00:00:00',
'2017-04-01 00:00:00' => '2017-04-30 00:00:00',
'2017-05-01 00:00:00' => '2017-05-31 00:00:00',
'2017-06-01 00:00:00' => '2017-06-30 00:00:00',
'2017-07-01 00:00:00' => '2017-07-31 00:00:00',
'2017-08-01 00:00:00' => '2017-08-31 00:00:00',
'2017-09-01 00:00:00' => '2017-09-30 00:00:00'
);

#open(my $fh , "+>/var/www/bin/filesample.txt");

foreach my $key(sort keys %hash) {
  chomp($key);
  #my $sql = "select distinct FID_CUST from session where DAT_END between ? and ?";
  my $sql = "select distinct FID_CUST from session where DAT_END between TIMESTAMP(?) and TIMESTAMP(?)";
  print "\$sql = $sql\n";
  my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
  $sth->execute($key,$hash{$key}) or die "Couldn't execute statement: $DBI::errstr";
  print "sth: $sth\n";

  while (my $arr = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref()){
    print "in while\n";
    print "@$arr\n";
  }
  $sth->finish();
}
#close FH;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

Here, i am not able to get what is wrong with the code as control is not going to while loop. Please suggest what can be done. I am using DB2 database. I am not getting any error but it simply won't show any output. I have used TIMESTAMP also with placeholders but it is showing some ambiguity error.

Comment: "showing some ambiguity error."???

Comment: Missing `use warnings;`.

Comment: DBD::DB2::db prepare failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0245N  The invocation of routine "TIMESTAMP" is ambiguous. The argument in position "1" does not have a best fit.  SQLSTATE=428F5
DBD::DB2::st execute failed: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0245N  The invocation of routine "TIMESTAMP" is ambiguous. The argument in position "1" does not have a best fit.  SQLSTATE=428F5
Could not run : [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0245N  The invocation of routine "TIMESTAMP" is ambiguous. The argument in position "1" does not have a best fit.  SQLSTATE=428F5

Comment: Someone pointed out the confusing mention of an "ambiguity error" but the question remains unchanged. Fix it.

Comment: @Dr Eval : Yes, i have changed the query, if you see, i have added another query and commented previous one. Also i have shared the error as above.

Comment: Not in comments, in the question itself. The question should be a concise statement of the problem with errors stated in full.

Comment: @Dr Eval : I did not change question because i am not sure whether i am using right syntax or code for the same. i have mentioned in general.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for `TIMESTAMP`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_timestamp.html) says:

> A character string or graphic string with an actual length of 14 that represents a valid date and time in the form `yyyyxxddhhmmss`, where `yyyy` is the year, `xx` is the month, `dd` is the day, `hh` is the hour, `mm` is the minute, and `ss` is the seconds.

You are passing strings of actual length 19 such as `'2017-01-01 00:00:00'`.

Pass timestamps formatted in the way DB2 expects them, e.g. `20170101000000`.

If that did not work, then try the advice given in [DB2 documentation for error SQL0245N](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00245n.html)

> This error is returned when an invocation of a function is ambiguous. This occurs when there are two or more possible candidate functions that satisfy the criteria for function resolution.
>
> ...
>
> **User response**
>
> Change the SQL statement to explicitly cast the argument to the desired data type, the definition of a function, or the SQL path to remove the ambiguity from the set of candidate functions and try again.

and change your query to:

```
select distinct FID_CUST 
from session 
where DAT_END between
     TIMESTAMP(cast(? as TIMESTAMP)) and
     TIMESTAMP(cast(? as TIMESTAMP))
```

or similar.

As I said, your question ***does not have any Perl content***. If the syntax I concocted for casting strings to `TIMESTAMP`s is incorrect, ask your database admin for the correct DB2 SQL syntax.

Comment: It looks like you do not have a Perl question.

Comment: The only error message you posted is one emitted by the database.

Answer (score 2):

Change all your timestamp literals from their current format

```
'2017-01-01 00:00:00' => '2017-01-31 00:00:00',
```

into

```
'2017-01-01-00.00.00.000000' => '2017-01-31-00.00.00.000000',
```